# Pass Rails Error message from model to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method in my model which parsers an API and returns the data:

```
def self.get_item_info(date, time, limit)
    url = URI.parse("#{end_point_url}/#{date}?mRange=#{time}&limit=#{limit}") 
           @response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
           if @response["ERROR"]
             flash[:notice] = { :notice => "Sorry, No Data returned. Message: #{@response["ERROR"]["errorMessage"]}" }
           else
             @data = []
             @items = @response["v1"]["items"]
             @items.each do |item|
               add_data(item["itemNbr"])
               @data << [@fam_id = item["FamId"],
               @item_nbr = item["itemNbr"],
               @item_desc = item["itemDesc"]]
              end
              return @data
      end    
 end
```

My controller:

```
def index
    if
      date = params[:date]
      time = params[:time]
      limit = params[:limit].to_i

        Product.get_item_info(date, time, limit)
        if @message
          redirect_to "/view_api", :flash => { :notice => "Sorry, No Data returned. Message: #{@message}" }
        else 
          @data 
        end
      end
  end
```

If an error is returned by the API, how can I redirect :back in my controller and flash the error message returned by the API. I initially had this logic in my controller, but moved it to my model for testing purposes.

Comment: Your model should raise exceptions on errors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your model method should be like:

```
def self.get_item_info(date, time, limit)
       url = URI.parse("#{end_point_url}/#{date}?mRange=#{time}&limit=#{limit}") 
       response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
       if response["ERROR"]
        return [nil, { :error => "Sorry, No Data returned. Message: #{response["ERROR"]["errorMessage"]}" }]
       else
         data = []
         items = response["v1"]["items"]
         items.each do |item|
           add_data(item["itemNbr"])
           data << [fam_id = item["FamId"],
           item_nbr = item["itemNbr"],
           item_desc = item["itemDesc"]]
          end
          return [data,{ :success => "true" }] 
  end    
end
```

then in your controller:

```
def index
  date = params[:date]
  time = params[:time]
  limit = params[:limit].to_i

    @data, @message = Product.get_item_info(date, time, limit)
    if @message[:error].present?
      redirect_to "/view_api", :flash => { :notice => @message[:error] }
    else 
      @data 
    end
  end
end
```

please check if there is any syntax or logical error. I just showed the way.

#### Notes:

You should not use any instance variables without any reason. specially in model.
If you do not care about specific error message then you can raise and exception in your model and use an begin .. rescue block in your controller to handle the exception